# Is there a way to run canonical livepatch on command ie run and check for updates only when i say

Tags: command-line

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to check for ubuntu patches when the program is executed and I was wondering if there's a way to check and validate if there's a new security patch available on command . If there is one what is the command line method to invoke it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it's clearly stated on the `canonical-livepatch help` page:

> ```
> canonical-livepatch - Canonical livepatch client
>
> VERSION:
>    10.5.6
>
> AUTHOR:
>    Canonical Livepatch Team
>
> COMMANDS:
>    config - configure livepatching on the machine
>    disable - disable livepatching on the machine
>    enable - enable livepatching on the machine
>    help - display help
>    kernel-upgrade-required - indicate whether a kernel upgrade is required
>    refresh - immediately download and apply any available livepatch
>    status - show kernel's livepatch status
> ```

So run `canonical-livepatch refresh` to do what you want (with `root` privileges of course).